# Why is the probability of extinction given by the probability generating function applied to 0?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am trying to understand branching processes and can't find a good explanation for why solving for the probability of extinction at time $n$ is given by 
$p^{(n)}(0)$ with the superscript representing function composition. I understand that composing the probability generating function over and over comes from the distribution for each generations population being identically distributed, but where does plugging in $s=0$ come in? It seems that this should just give you the constant term of some ugly expression.

I understand why solving for the fixed point of the pgf gives you a solution for the probability of going extinct in finite time, is this related and is there a way to connect the two concepts neatly?

Comment: everything is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process#Extinction_problem what do you want more ?

Comment: @user1952009: I'm all in favour of pointing out when questions are already answered in Wikipedia, but in the present case I don't see where that article substitutes $0$ into a generating function.

Comment: @joriki : $d_m = h(d_{m-1})$ with $d_0 = 0$ (with $d_m$ the probability of extinction at generation $m$)

Comment: @user1952009: I see. I think that sufficiently implicit in the article to warrant making it explicit in a brief answer.

Comment: @joriki : what is amazing is that everything converges nicely, $d_m$ is a probability hence in $[0,1[$ and the generating function $h(z)  =\sum_{k=0}^\infty p_k z^k$ has radius of convergence at least $1$ since again $p_k$ are probabilities (the case $d_m =1$ implying that $h(z)$ is a polynomial !)

Comment: @user1952009 That was pretty much sufficient to help me, had it been an answer I would have accepted it. I didn't catch it (and had been perusing textbooks rather than wiki).